# Lion: Application's window size doesn't persist after quit/re-open

Tags: applications, display, skim

(Disclaimer: I'm not sure if my question is isolated to Skim.app – if so, it's fine if someone changes the title to reflect that – or if it's a Lion thing.)

I'm using Skim to read PDFs.

Every time I …

1. Open a document
2. Resize the window to cover my whole screen
3. Quit the application
4. Re-open the document

… the application's window revert to small size (about 2/3 of my screen instead of the whole screen.

I find this very annoying, as I expect the application's window size to persist after closing and re-opening the app.

Comment: Does this happen with other apps? If not, then it's a Skim-specific thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find the window size of one app not retaining the window size value after closing it, the suspect is the .plist for that app. ~/Library/Preferences/ should contain the file. Deleting it while the app is closed and re-opening it will forcibly rebuild it with minimal negative impact to the app itself.

Comment: Tested that, to no avail. In fact, I installed Skim just a few days ago (on a fresh clean install of Lion just earlier, and have also repaired permissions since then) so it would have been fairly surprising if it's the plist. I'll see if this is the same in other apps, otherwise I'll contact Skim's developer. (Just curious if anyone else expreience this in Skim...?) Anyone willing to try on their Lion?